# Who are these characters in Thanos Annual #1 (2014)...?

Tags: marvel, character-identification

Who are these Marvel characters in *[Thanos Annual #1](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Thanos_Annual_Vol_1_1)* (2014)...?

My guesses are:

1st row: x

2nd row: Eternity, Infinity

3rd row: x, x, x, x

4th row: Galactus, x, x, Odin, x, x

[image]

Comment: First row: Living Tribunal

Comment: Third row: ?, Master Order, Lord Chaos, ?

Comment: Leftmost and rightmost on the third row are Mistress Love and Sire Hate, respectively. Third character on the bottom looks like Kronos to me.

Comment: Is it just me, or does this depiction of Master Order look like an irritated Charles Xavier?

Comment: The colors don't match Kirby's but the head design of the Celestial on the bottom row most closely matches that of the One Above All.

Answer (score 10):

Starting from the bottom and working up:

1st Row, left to right: Galactus, a Celestial, Kronos, Odin, Zeus, The Stranger

2nd row: Mistress Love, Master Order, Lord Chaos, Master Hate

3rd Row: Eternity, Infinity

4th row: Living Tribunal

Comment: Is the planet not Ego?

Comment: The picture at [this entry](http://omniversal-battlefield.wikia.com/wiki/Abstract_Beings) is expandable and has most of these characters labeled on it. (Not Kronos or Odin.)

Comment: I don't think so. In this panel, Thanos is basically showing a hierarchy of where he ranks the various beings in terms of power. The planet appears to be just background, and not part of the rankings.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the fireball next to Eternity and Infinity is the Phoenix. Remember it's stated the true form is unknown, it only assumes the shape of a bird to communicate with intelligent life. Also in Marvel comics, the Watcher stated that the Phoenix is 2nd to the Creator (TOAA). In another it states the Dark phoenix is an Omniversal being.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you have evidence to support your answer, you need to edit it in, not post it separately.  And even if Dark Phoenix is cosmically powerful, you should demonstrate that she is represented as a ball of flame elsewhere.

Comment: Aside from the fact that I've never seen the Phoenix drawn as a fireball (rather than a firebird) before, another reason I don't believe that fireball was meant to be the Phoenix is that the issue in question (_Thanos Annual #1_ (2014)) was written by Jim Starlin as a prequel to _Infinity War_, and while the other characters named repeatedly appeared in Starlin stories such as _Infinity War_, the Phoenix never did. The Phoenix generally only appeared in X-Men comics around the time of (and prior to) the publication of _Infinity War_ in the early '90s.